# How can I convert image to arrays using Java code?

Tags: java, python, android, arrays, image

I'm trying to set up an MLKit detection project on Android using Tensorflow library, I have got false values on the output using Tensorflow lite ( different values than Frozen model inference ).

I doubt that the problem is with the input ( image ), So I want to compare the two same images that I have.

To do this task,  I have used PIL image and numpy libraries on python to get bytes arrays, and I have converted the drawable image to bitmap and from bitmap to bytes arrays.

I don't know if the function `np.asarray` should give the same value as those two functions below:

Java code:

```java
    private float[][][][] bitmapToInputArray() {
    // [START mlkit_bitmap_input]
    Bitmap bitmap= getYourInputImage();
    int batchNum = 0;
    float[][][][] input = new float[1][112][112][3];
    for (int x = 0; x < 112; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 112; y++) {
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
            // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
            // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
            input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel))/ 255.0f;
            input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel)) / 255.0f;
            input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel))/ 255.0f;
            Log.i("Input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y][0]);
            Log.i("input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y][1]);

        }
    }
    // [END mlkit_bitmap_input]

    return input;
}
public byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        return stream.toByteArray();
    }finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(ThemedSpinnerAdapter.Helper.class.getSimpleName(), "ByteArrayOutputStream was not closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
private Bitmap getYourInputImage() {
    // This method is just for show
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image2.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,112,112,true);
    Bitmap bitmap2= bitmapp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    return bitmap2;
}

    byte[] bytes=convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap1);
    Log.i("byte",""+ Arrays.toString(bytes));
    float[][][][] inp = new float[1][112][112][3];
    inp=bitmapToInputArray();
    Log.i("byte2",""+Arrays.toString(inp[0]));
```

Python script:

```py
    img = Image.open("irisdata-300VW_Dataset_2015_12_14-017-000880.jpg")
img.load()
img = img.resize((112, 112), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
print(str(image_to_byte_array(img)))


# Normalize to [0, 1]
data = np.asarray( img, dtype="float32")
print(data)
```

- Output of java code:

> 2019-08-20 19:01:13.589 1513-1513/com.example.irisdetection I/byte: [-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -37, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -37, 0, 67, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -64, 0, 17, 8, 0, 112, 0, 112, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1, -1, -60, 0, 29, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5, 10, 3, 2, 1, -1, -60, 0, 69, 16, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 5, 4, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 17, 33, 0, 7, 18, 19, 49, 8, 34, 65, 81, 97, 20, 35, 113, -127, 9, 21, 50, 51, -111, -95, -79, 36, 66, -63, -47, -16, 22, 23, 67, 82, 83, -31, 37, 52, 98, 114, -15, 99, 115, -126, -125, -94, -1, -60, 0, 28, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 8, 0, 1, -1, -60, 0, 55, 17, 0, 0, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 17, 33, 0, 6, 49, 65, 81, 97, 18, 19, 113, 7, 20, 35, -127, -111, -95, -79, -16, -47, 34, -63, -31, 21, 36, 67, -15, 8, 22, 50, 51, -1, -38, 0, 12, 3, 1, 0, 2, 17, 3, 17, 0, 63, 0, -28, -105, 115, 116, 26, 45, 98, -97, 117, 74, -71, -31, -57, -88, 40, -73, 93, 88, -83, 83, 89, 39, 41, -20, -43, 40, -7, 28, 115, 12, -100, -52, -116, -88, 78, 53, -45, 84, -49, -53, 102, 114, 124, 34, -52, -20, -3, -72, 91, -115, 6, -58, -120, -76, -5, -102, -126, 71, 36, -107, 43, -97, -11, 61, 93, -17, 78, 96, 63, 115, -35, -52, 8, -3, -30, -89, -40, -26, 117, -40, 29, -70, 107, 106, 21, 112, 86, -36, 7, 73, 36, 120, -9, 30, -19, -18, -48, -56, 86, -79, -88, -31, -106, -105, 36, -53, -53, 103, 30, -92, 121, 24, -120, 76, 47, -7, -15, -99, 54, 103, 44, -88, -107, 42, -57, 98, 107, 90, 83, -98, 105, 20, -21, 43, 126, 53, -117, 106, 58, -71, -116, 84, -114, 58, -11, 22, 53, 77, -84, 119, 47, -34, -14, -52, 72, 102, 127, -68, -57, -61, 77, -78, 126, -35, 18, -79, 112, 9, 38, 41, 40, 50, 3, 104, 63, -7, -64, 66, 97, -100, -66, -115, -115, 59, 43, -119, 21, 43, -50, -111, 79, 62, 82, -55, -72, 64, 70, -76, -92, -6, 5, 119, -54, -42, 15, -40, -126, -36, -81, 86, 109, 8, 55, 69, -62, 114, 31, -39, -30, 125, 65, 65, 9, 120, -47, -111, -24, -48, 36, -55, 56, -58, 49, -12, 103, 52, -14, 77, -24, -68, 12, -41, 24, -38, -49, 45, -6, 122, -80, -104, -106, -88, 32, -76, 92, 72, -67, 51, -13, 95, 92, -2, 105, -90, 112, -85, -1, 0, 101, -21, 110, -105, 72, -35, 117, -93, 21, -22, -48, 56, 84, 56, 50, 9, -62, -33, -74, 105, 35, -25, -99, 126, 42, 71, -89, -126, -86, -2, 91, 77, 119, -59, -67, 56, 86, 101, 29, -50, -116, -41, 28, -83, 78, 1, 2, 59, 85, 78, 103, -82, -120, -120, -119, -16, 84, -8, -81, -82, -43, -119, 2, 73, -74, -32, 34, 124, -95, -91, 103, -120, -56, 48, -108, -3, 55, 10, -128, 72, 44, 54, -11, 68, -43, -117, 63, 85, 41, 75, -67, -81, -115, 104, 11, -128, 98, 30, 84, -99, -90, 117, -103, -47, 13, 32, -111, 99, 59, 8, -30, 120, -85, 59, -38, -8, 42, 116, -50, -67, 51, -25, -116, 109, -17, 6, -128, 85, 123, 72, 34, 46, 60, 28, -72, -8, 39, 69, -49, -97, -13, -38, -77, -28, -17, 107, 125, -75, -103, -113, -97, 108, 110, -34, -19, -88, 0, 69, -53, 80, 84, -87, 74, -114, 69, 34, -82, -124, 81, -94, 97, 124, -4, -70, 109, 40, -94, 118, -112, -19, 67, 109, 76, -114, -54, -2, -25, 36, -118, -104, -30, 35, -122, -39, -111, -90, 10, 79, 39, 61, 73, -53, 69, -41, 25, 93, 116, -12, -38, -87, 70, -4, -59, 84, -83, 100, 30, 67, 47, -65, 103, 51, 120, 107, -94, 36, 68, -124, -63, -31, -56, 39, 44, -58, -127, -112, -53, 110, -125, -106, 118, 97, 30, -117, 46, 58, 100, -68, 46, 110, 123, -51, -41, -89, 84, -4, -4, -68, 126, 91, 123, -44, -30, 3, -39, -107, 80, 92, 92, 89, -18, -89, -34, 105, -29, -4, 83, -11, -38, 47, -70, -19, -17, 10, -4, -89, 8, -43, 90, 49, 40, -14, -36, 1, -72, -111, -56, -113, 86, 101, 90, -103, 31, 125, 62, -13, -29, -32, -102, -90, -60, -55, -43, 90, 28, 126, 23, 56, 106, -118, -115, -30, 114, 47, -106, 5
>   2019-08-20 19:01:13.590 1513-1513/com.example.irisdetection I/byte2: [[[F@8bc81c1, [[F@4123d66, [[F@d5d68a7, [[F@ed2a154, [[F@7ce78fd, [[F@c74c9f2, [[F@66de843, [[F@627ec0, [[F@50ea7f9, [[F@201933e, [[F@57cc59f, [[F@250c6ec, [[F@f88cab5, [[F@7ffa54a, [[F@d721cbb, [[F@1f965d8,

- Output of python code:

[image: Python output]

How can I get the same output of the python code with Java code using bitmap as an input?